How to resume my previous session in Ubuntu 20.04 if I have suspended the session?
Yesterday while working on Ubuntu, I was doing some installation. It was taking a long time, so I suspended the session from the menu section of Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu under VirtualBox machine. When I tried to resume my Ubuntu screen it showed a completely black screen. When I moved the mouse around the screen, nothing happened. The mouse cursor did not respond. Is there any workaround for this problem?


You'll need to clarify your details; you've tagged your question as being about Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 (Ubuntu 14.04 is years past it's end of standard support & thus off-topic here), but you mention in the title 20.2 which is not a valid release of Ubuntu (there was no release in 2020-February thus no 20.02). Clear details allow us to better provide advice; whilst we currently don't know what you're running, have you tried switching to text terminal? or issued direct commands to kernel to see if its responding (ie. bypassing any stuck UI/GUI)...
